# Is it possible to configure ANTLR grammar to use two token having the same structure?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

For the below grammar,

```html
grammar names;

fullname : TITLE? FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME;

TITLE : 'Mr.' | 'Ms.' | 'Mrs.' ;

FIRST_NAME : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+ ;

LAST_NAME : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+ ;

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ -> skip ;
```

When parsing input like "Mr. John Smith", it throw exception

```
 mismatched input 'Smith' expecting LAST_NAME
```

Is it possible to configure ANTLR to handle this case?
If not possible, what could be the alternative way to handle it?

Please note that it's not limited to this simple case.

Comment: Not much point really, just define NAME and `fullname : TITLE? NAME NAME`

Comment: I need to differentiate between FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME to use them later in the application, so it cannot be considered as the same NAME. Also, it's not limited to this simple case, I have more rules that should be defined with the same way. So, is it possible to use ANTLR to handle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no syntactic difference between `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`; you just need to assign them.

```
grammar names;

fullname : TITLE? first=NAME last=NAME;

TITLE : 'Mr.' | 'Ms.' | 'Mrs.' ;

NAME : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+ ;

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ -> skip ;
```

Then you can call `get("first")` and `get("last")` to extract the parsed values out of the match.

Comment: Thanks Jacob for pointing to the "label" part. But when I changed it in the grammar, I got this error "error(50): syntax error: unterminated rule (missing ';') detected at 'first :' while looking for rule element

Missing rule definition"

Comment: @vanilla, it should be `=` instead of `:`. @Jacob, I took the liberty to also change your phrasing of "labelling" into "assigning", since "labels" are something different in ANTLR terms: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules